# How to write vertical text in html like a banner?

Tags: html, css

I need to write vertical text. I just want the text to look like one below other.

Required Output:

> A
>
> P
>
> P
>
> L
>
> E

I cannot use `rotate` property. And I dont want to modify my html. What could be the best way? Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: What if you made the width of the element that contains this text the size of a single letter, so that each letter were wrapped to the next line. Use `word-wrap:break-word`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

HTML:

```
<p class="vertical-text">ABCD</p>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-text{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 0;  
}
```

Comment: Oops, I thought about word-wrap for a while too.. but i couldn't think of making the width zero to wrap it letter wise.. thank you!